# bytes32 to uint conversion is incorrect

Tags: solidity, web3js, bytes32

I instantiate the following contract with `_number` as `10`. When I check the value of `number`, I get `72370055773322622139731865630429942408293740416025352524660990004945706024960`. Is this a problem with my contract, or is this a web3 bug?

```
contract Thing{
  uint public number;
  function Thing(bytes32 _number){
    number = uint(_number);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the web3 code you use to instantiate it?

Comment: @NickJohnson I'm using browser solidity https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`72370055773322622139731865630429942408293740416025352524660990004945706024960` is `0xa000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L` - or `10` in hex, left shifted. Without seeing your web3 code, it's difficult to say why it was parsed this way, but it seems likely web3 treated your input as a single byte byte string, and left-aligned it into the bytes32 argument.

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

There are some oddities when using `bytes32` as function parameters.

From [Solidity Features - Byte Arrays](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#byte-arrays):

> PT Basic support for variable-length byte arrays. This includes
>
> - bytes type for storage variables
> - msg.data is of bytes type and contains the calldata
> - functions taking arbitrary parameters (call, sha3, ...) can be called with bytes arguments.
> - copying between msg.data and bytes storage variables
>
> What is `not` possible yet:
>
> - `function parameters of bytes type`
> - local variables of bytes type
> - index or slice access

---

## Details

I use the following source code based on your source code:

```
contract ByteToInt {
    uint public number;
    bytes32 public thebytes32;

    function ByteToInt(bytes32 _number) {
        thebytes32 = _number;
        number = uint(_number);
    }
}
```

And flattened it to:

```
var byteToIntSource='contract ByteToInt { uint public number; bytes32 public thebytes32;  function ByteToInt(bytes32 _number) { thebytes32 = _number; number = uint(_number); }}'
```

Ran it in `geth --dev console`:

```
> var byteToIntSource='contract ByteToInt { uint public number; bytes32 public thebytes32;  function ByteToInt(bytes32 _number) { thebytes32 = _number; number = uint(_number); }}'
undefined
```

Compiled it:

```
> var byteToIntCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(byteToIntSource);
undefined
```

Inserted it into the blockchain:

```
> var byteToIntContract = web3.eth.contract(byteToIntCompiled.ByteToInt.info.abiDefinition);
var byteToInt = byteToIntContract.new(10, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: byteToIntCompiled.ByteToInt.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
...
Contract mined! Address: 0x49617e1728c53a3e31ccf21faf6ba344af90f04c
```

And checked the values:

```
> byteToInt.thebytes32()
"0xa000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

> byteToInt.number()
7.237005577332262213973186563042994240829374041602535252466099000494570602496e+76
```

I executed the following statements in Java:

```
BigInteger num = new BigInteger("a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 16);
System.out.println(num.toString(10));
```

And the results are:

```
72370055773322622139731865630429942408293740416025352524660990004945706024960
```

So `10` is being encoded as the first byte in your bytes32 variable, and the `uint(...)` cast is converting the whole bytes32 data into a `uint`.

Checking how web3 converts the decimal values into the parameters, I tried sending in `0xabc` into the constructor by using the decimal equivalent of `2748`:

```
var byteToInt = byteToIntContract.new(2748, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: byteToIntCompiled.ByteToInt.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
...
Contract mined! Address: 0xb086848ed791c87a6659ed17fb6fd85e37aae97b
...
> byteToInt.thebytes32()
"0xabc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> byteToInt.number()
7.7684731744176002203118424512664641303902811977827214350690781458433906311168e+76
```

Try out the following:

```
var byteToInt = byteToIntContract.new(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abc, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: byteToIntCompiled.ByteToInt.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + 
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
  }
)
...
> byteToInt.thebytes32()
"0xabc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```